# What is the best resources Azure family size for E-Commerce

Tags: azure, virtual-machines, cloud, website, azure-web-apps

I'm trying to increase the Azure VM family size from B series to be bigger, I'm hosing web application that runs E-Commerce , As you expect multiple product photos, customer browsing the products I have around 2000 product in the store.

What is the best resources Azure family size for E-Commerce in this scenario?
I am receiving multiple error from server side for the over demand traffic and storage of BLOB

Answer (score 0):

There's no way we can answer this with the information provided. Azure VM Sizes are based mainly on CPU, Memory and Disk, you need to assess your application to determine it's requirements in these areas and pick a machine size that is appropriate, there is no generic "ecommerce" size. You could be servicing 1 request an hour, or 2 million.

If you are getting errors, then look at the Azure monitor metrics and determine where you are hitting limits and look to increase them.

Comment: Ok, when I start from the normal size then moved to production server, it keep stopping on AppGW due to overdemand requests of the web application

Comment: So benchmark the number of requests you need to support and work out the hardware you need to support it.